# Specify intervals for Location Manager to broadcast current location in Android

Tags: java, android, locationmanager

Is there any way to specify the time intervals that the Location Manager broadcasts the current location?

I am using a method called startListening:

```
public void startListening() {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 
                0, 
                0, 
                this
        );
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`public void requestLocationUpdates (String provider, long minTime, float minDistance, LocationListener listener, Looper looper)`

Registers the current activity to be notified periodically by the named provider. Periodically, the supplied LocationListener will be called with the current Location or with status updates.

It may take a while to receive the most recent location. If an immediate location is required, applications may use the getLastKnownLocation(String) method.

In case the provider is disabled by the user, updates will stop, and the `onProviderDisabled(String)` method will be called. As soon as the provider is enabled again, the onProviderEnabled(String) method will be called and location updates will start again.

**The frequency of notification may be controlled** using the `minTime` and `minDistance` parameters. If `minTime` is greater than 0, the LocationManager could potentially rest for `minTime` milliseconds between location updates to conserve power. If `minDistance` is greater than 0, a location will only be broadcasted if the device moves by `minDistance` meters. To obtain notifications as frequently as possible, set both parameters to 0.

Background services should be careful about setting a sufficiently high `minTime` so that the device doesn't consume too much power by keeping the GPS or wireless radios on all the time. In particular, values under 60000ms are not recommended.

The supplied Looper is used to implement the callback mechanism.

Parameters

- provider the name of the provider
  with which to register
- minTime  the
  minimum time interval for
  notifications, in milliseconds. This
  field is only used as a hint to
  conserve power, and actual time
  between location updates may be
  greater or lesser than this value.
- minDistance  the minimum distance
  interval for notifications, in meters
- listener a whose onLocationChanged(Location)
  method will be called for each
  location update
- looper   a Looper
  object whose message queue will be
  used to implement the callback
  mechanism.

Throws

`IllegalArgumentException`  if provider is null or doesn't exist
`IllegalArgumentException`  if listener is null
`IllegalArgumentException`  if looper is null
`SecurityException` if no suitable permission is present for the provider.

Comment: but is it the lesser of the 2 that it picks? If minTime is 10000 and minDistance is 0, could it still potentially update every second?

Comment: The doc doesn't tell us how it's working exactly, it can be. Anyway don't rely on the interval value.

Comment: This actually happens if the minDistance parameter is set to 0 on actual devices. Location updates occur every second regardless the min interval. one work around this is to use a timer task to register for location updates and then cancel it at the first location update you get and set it off again after the required interval.

Answer (score 1):

minTime : the minimum time interval for notifications, in **milliseconds**. This field is only used as a hint to conserve power, and actual time between location updates may be greater or lesser than this value.

minDistance:    the minimum distance interval for notifications, in **meters**

Answer (score 0):

```
    locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 9000, 500,locListener);
```

// 60000 Is 1 Minute and 100 is KM

Above you have 9000 (Nine Seconds) and 500 which is if the location has moved more than 500KM

Comment: I think you mean metres (m) not kilometres (km).